EditText cursor slightly overlaps hint
Our designer noticed that our cursor slightly overlaps the hint text of an EditText:

Upon investigation, we found this appears to be the default behavior for whatever reason, and is even present in other applications:
Slack:

Gmail (slightly less noticeable due to the dark colors):

Additionally, I spun up a brand to test application with a single EditText, and further confirmed that the overlap seems to be default behavior. How can this overlap be fixed or mitigated? Adding paddingStart to the EditText doesn't work, as it moves the whole input area, including the cursor. There appears to be no official documentation about this.
The following is what we'd like to achieve regarding the cursor position:


"How can this overlap be fixed or mitigated?" -- have you tried adding a space character to the beginning of your hint text? Alternatively, switch to Compose, and control the hint positioning as part of your design system implementation.

@CommonsWare Thanks for the prompt reply! Yes, I have tried adding a single space character to the hint text, but that produces a rather large gap between the cursor start and hint start. We'd like the cursor start to be precisely at the start of the hint text, if possible. I can add a screenshot of what we'd like to achieve, if that would be helpful to readers.

"I can add a screenshot of what we'd like to achieve, if that would be helpful to readers" -- it might help. However, in the end, my guess is that the solution will be "stop using the hint in EditText and do something else".

@CommonsWare I've added an image of what we'd like to achieve regarding the cursor position. I'm not sure what you're suggesting regarding not using a hint, what else could be used? We definitely want to have a hint, or something that looks like a hint! Adding real text and styling it as a hint, removing it when the user begins typing, doesn't seem like it would work as the overlap issue seems to occur with "real" text input as well.

"I'm not sure what you're suggesting regarding not using a hint, what else could be used?" -- if the background of the EditText is transparent, layer it over a TextView that serves as the hint. Or, see how the Material form of EditText handles things like the trailing icon (e.g., the password field eye) and see if that gives you inspiration. "the overlap issue seems to occur with "real" text input as well" -- it is unclear what you mean by this.

@CommonsWare Ok, I'll consider the TextView workaround. Regarding my comment, I was simply pointing out that the cursor overlap issue appears to also occur with real text input, not just a hint. I suppose that was expected, but I wanted to call it out.

@Orbit you can add  android:letterSpacing="0.11" to create space between letters so your cursor adds a little space between hint.you can change "0.11" value by your adjust
